# Can not make static method non static

Tags: php

I am running one pear library in my local server. The library has been developed making static method non-static on the child class. Have a look at [their documentation](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.intro-autobuilding.php) But when I run the library in my local server (using PHP 5.4 ) then it generates the fatal error.

I have also written a very simple php program to replicate it which generates the same error message.

```
class Test {
    static function mytest($num) {
        return $num + 10;
    }
}


class childTest extends Test {
    function mytest() {
        echo Test::mytest(10);
 }
}
```

"Fatal error: Cannot make static method Test::mytest() non static in class childTest"

Does anyone knows how to tackle this error while running those pear libraries or it's purely because of using the latest version of PHP?

Comment: Why do you need to make it non-static? In the documentation class `DataObjects_Grp` is written by library user, right?

Comment: @GermanLashevich :  The static method staticGet is called in a non static method staticGet (same name) in child class which creates a fetal error in my php compiler. I have mentioned the php version.

Comment: Can you edit the child class?

Comment: @GermanLashevich : That's what I had to do to avoid this error.

Comment: So, what is wrong with @yuanming's answer? Just make the child's method static too.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
class Test {
    static function mytest($num) {
        return $num + 10;
    }
}


class childTest extends Test {
    static function mytest() {
        echo Test::mytest(10);
    }
}
```

need to use static constructors

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: What is the origin of the error ? In DB_DataObjects the sources of the clases are generated automatically, why is now well constructed, with "static" in the function ?